# What is NXT's Genesis Account's Passphrase / Password?

Tags: nxt, genesis-block

I remember there was a passphrase/password that gave you access to NXT's genesis account even though you can't do anything with it once you get in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Genesis Account Number

The genesis account number is **1739068987193023818 (NXT-MRCC-2YLS-8M54-3CMAJ)**.

### Genesis Account Passphrase

The passphrase “**It was a bright cold day in April, and the clocks were striking thirteen.**” gives any user access to the genesis account. It is the opening line of George Orwell’s ‘1984’, which begins on the 4th April 1984.

Even if you got in, it would be a negative balance which means you wont be able to send anything out. People use it to use it as a blackhole to send their nxt or assets to, since anything that goes in wont be coming back out.

[image]